# Way too long words

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my solution to the "way too long words" problem on codeforces.
Even though I am getting correct output, but still it has been reported as the wrong answer to a question by codeforces.

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A 
(link to the question)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //charAt() is an inbuilt method which can read a string letter by letter
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        //System.out.println("how many words do you wish to enter?");
        n=input.nextInt();
        String[] words=new String[n+1];
        for(int i=0;i<n+1;i++)
        {
            words[i]=input.nextLine();
        }

        for(int j=0;j<n+1;j++)
        {
            if(words[j].length()<10)
            {
                System.out.print(words[j]);
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print(words[j].charAt(0));
                System.out.print(words[j].length()-2);
                System.out.print(words[j].charAt(words[j].length()-1));
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please take the [tour] to better understand why StackOverflow exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the condition, you are only skipping words below the length of 10 but not considering the words with exact of 10 length.

```
 if(words[j].length()<=10)
 {
        System.out.print(words[j]);
 }
```

Change the condition it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop for int j do something like this -

```
if(words[j].length()<=10) //boundary check
        {
            System.out.print(words[j]);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println(words[j].charAt(0).toString() + words[j].length()-2 + words[j].charAt(words[j].length()-1).toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Because where r you entering string in your program. Once you run, you will get to know.
Btw this is the solution of actual problem.
 public static void main(String[] args){
String str=null;
        int count=0;
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter string :");
        str=scanner.nextLine();
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            count ++;
        }
        char first=str.charAt(0);
        char last=str.charAt(count-1);
        int num=count-2;
        System.out.println("abbreviation is :" +first+num+last); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream> 
using namespace std;

string change_abb(string str)
{
    string result;
  if(str.length()>10)
  {
      int k=str.length()-2;
      stringstream ss;  
      ss<<k;  
      string s;  
      ss>>s;
    result+=str[0];
    result+=s;
    result+=str[str.length()-1];
  }
  else
  {
      result=str;
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  string in_str;
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin>>in_str;
    cout<<change_abb(in_str)<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer in Python 3 ([Answer accepted by Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/problemset/submission/71/110795636))

```
n = int(input())
p=""
for i in range(n):
    s = input()
    if len(s)>10:
        p = s[0]+str((len(s)-2))+s[len(s)-1]
    else:
        p=s
    print(p)
```